# What's the WPF equivalent of a Winform ToolStripContainer?

Tags: c#, wpf, toolstripcontainer

**Or what control/method I should be using to achieve the same?**

I've just started transitioning from Winforms over to WPF and I tried googling as well as search on SO for the same question but to no avail. So I'm guessing it has to do more with the fact that WPF has a different method of approach entirely. I tried looking at DockPanel but I'm still quite unsure how to handle the menus/orientations and especially user-interations to reposition said menus and toolbars.

I know there are a lot of ways to achieve the same thing in WPF. But even so, what's the standard method for handling Menus like how a toolstripcontainer does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box control equivalent for ToolStripContainer in WPF.

But there are lots of commercial controls such as [Telerik RadToolBar](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/toolbar.aspx) or [DevExpress DXBars](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/Bar_Menu/). Click the links to see their preview.

Commercial controls for WPF are mature for years so they are worth to buy.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. +1 for mentioning if out-of-the-box was even possible or not.